# Cache channel service not working for Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, cache-channel-service

I am using DD4T 2.2(using CIL) and SDL Web 8.5. I have installed cache channel service dependent on(using $arguments += "++DependsOn=SDLWebDiscoveryService") discovery service. I have configured discovery micro service, Content micro service and Deployer micro service. I can't see any significant improvement in performance of my web application. To verify if the cache channel service working, I have setup the log mode to debug. I can't see any log while browsing any page. Can anyone please suggest if I am missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When generated Trace level log for micro services like discovery, content and deployer I found that cache channel service is generating logs and working fine. When published a component, I can see log generated for cache channel service, deployer, content etc. When we configured CIL level caching in DD4T application we found significant improvement.

Comment: So as we have done some more testing on this I don't believe this is really the answer. While setting up a Long Term cache with the CIL does for sure help that cache is not subject to invalidation calls for publishing events. The caching layers at the content and discovery layer are still not providing any benefit for additional performance gain.

Comment: I am currently configuring the Cache Channel Service. It is up and running now, but I wonder isn't it needed to register it as a Capability?